# TreeView ItemSource binding to ViewModel not updating xaml control's Items

Tags: .net, wpf, user-controls, treeview, prism

I am creating a UserControl (let's call it ViewTree) wrapping a TreeView element. In ViewTree.xaml.cs I have a `Source` dependency property:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty SourceProperty
    = DependencyProperty.Register (
        "Source",
        typeof (ObservableCollection<TreeItem>),
        typeof (ViewTree),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata (new ObservableCollection<TreeItem>(), OnSourceChanged)
    );
public ObservableCollection<TreeItem> Source
{
    get { return (ObservableCollection<TreeItem>)GetValue(SourceProperty); }
    set { SetValue(SourceProperty, value); }
}
```

...so that the consumer of this UserControl can do input binding:

```
<features:ViewTree Source="{Binding Path=...}">
```

In the ViewTree UserControl, however, I don't really want to bind directly to this DependencyProperty. Instead, I want to bind to another property in the ViewModel (with Prism), so I did this in ViewTree.xaml.cs:

```
private static void OnSourceChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var nextTreeSource = e.NewValue as ObservableCollection<TreeItem>;
    if (nextTreeSource == null)
    {
        return;
    }
    var viewTree = d as ViewTree;
    viewTree.UpdateTreeSource(nextTreeSource);
}
public void UpdateTreeSource(ObservableCollection<TreeItem> treeSource)
{
    var vm = trvMenu.DataContext as ViewTreeViewModel;
    vm.TreeSource = treeSource;
}
```

In my ViewTree.xaml, I have the following, and the tree nodes present normally:

```
<TreeView Name="trvMenu" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=TreeSource}">
```

However, when I attempt to access `trvMenu.Items` in ViewTree.xaml.cs, it shows empty. I put a breakpoint after `viewTree.UpdateTreeSource(nextTreeSource);` and can verify that `viewTree.trvMenu.Items` has children inside.

If I bind directly to the DependencyProperty, it works fine, but I would still prefer the ViewModel binding.

I would appreciate if anyone could point me where I did wrong or is it just the way WPF works?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "with Prism" means that you rely on Prism to create the user control's view model for you?

Comment: yeah, I have `prism:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True"` in my xaml and register the mapping for UserControl with ViewModel class during init.

Comment: It's unclear what UpdateTreeSource is supposed to do. It does not change the Binding of the Source property. Instead, it changes a property in the DataContext. That looks odd.

Comment: `UpdateTreeSource` intentionally changes the VM of the context ViewTree user control, which I wanted to use for binding. `Source` DP was just an input bridge for the consumer and the UC.

Anyway, there is nothing wrong with DP and VM binding, it was just a bug in the design. Sorry and thanks everyone.

Comment: This is not how you design controls. You want to allow your control to be used with different view model classes or data contexts. You don't backup your control internally with a "view model".  You add code-behind files or classes that contain logic and properties for thiss control. You must bind the TreeView to the Source property directly (or manually assign it). Don't use a "view model"  internally. If your control would be directly linked to a data source like reading directly from a database, then a view model would make sense. But usually controls passively display data and not manage it

Comment: OnSourceChanged should update the TreeViews ItemsSource and not any view model clases. You control should not know the DataContex.

Answer (score 0):

After a little more debugging, I found the issue, and it was completely my fault, nothing to do with DP or VM binding.

I have 2 consumers of ViewTree control. In ViewTree I subscribes to an event, and when it fires, both ViewTree elements invoke the handler.

The exception was thrown on one of the consumers' ViewTree, where TreeSource wasn't initialised.